# Orders placed through admin

Tags: orders, backend

Is there any possible method to query all orders placed through admin ( backend orders ) using SQL?

The case is to differentiate frontend and backend orders. 
What exactly I'm trying to achieve is to copy user details from all orders placed from Admin to a new table to integrate with a third-party application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the orders placed from the backend have the field `remote_ip` set to `null`.
So you can filter using an sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order where remote_ip IS NULL;
```

Or via code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('remote_ip', array('null'=>true));
```

Comment: Thanks Marius!
The SQL query works just fine! :)